How $k$-edge connected blocks are connected in graph
I have found a proof for the following statement:

A connected graph is $k$-edge connected if and only if all its blocks are $k$-edge connected.

My proof is largely similar to this one, but I am having trouble conceptualizing the something. Suppose that all blocks of $G$ are $k$-edge connected. If we remove $k-1$ edges from $G$ we remove at most $k-1$ edges from a block of $G$. Hence the resulting blocks are connected.
But why is it that in the resulting graph a block is connected to a neighbouring block either by an edge or a cut vertex? It must be the case, but wouldn't removing all the edges connected to a cut vertex disconnect the entire graph, and so would removing all edges connecting the neighbouring blocks?
While it seems intuitive I can't explain why. Any help is appreciated.

I'm not sure exactly where your confusion comes from. By definition, you cannot remove all edges incident to a vertex by removing $k-1$ edges; each cut vertex has at least $k$ neighbours in each of the blocks it is in. Also note that if $k\geq 2$, $G$ has no cut edges, so you cannot have the scenario where two blocks are separated by an edge cut.
